# The value becomes blank when loop the array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I get the data from API and the structure like this

```
[
    {keyword: ["123","456","789"] , name :"hello" },
    {keyword: ["abc","def","ghi"] , name :"bye" },
    {keyword: ["987","654","321"] , name :"hello" }
]
```

I decode it and use for loop to process the data

```
for($i = 0, $l = count($result); $i < $l; ++$i) {
  echo join(',' , $result[0]->keyword);
}
```

and i got

```
 ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

the i try to dump the array in the loop , the result is

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }
```

But I can use the data out of the loop

```
echo join(',' , $result[0]->keyword);
//123,456,789
var_dump($result[0]->keyword);
//array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "XXXXXXX" [1]=> string(9) "XXXXXXXX" [2]=> string(12) "XXXXXXXXXX" }
```

All other data in the data can be used and no encoding problem, why only this array's content being blank?

Comment: Show us what `var_dump($result);` gives you. (Output a `<pre>` before, or copy from source code view.)

Comment: Who downvoted me? I think this is the expected output https://eval.in/790378

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @Steve this is an `l` not a `1`  but I agree should be  better to name it something like `len`

Comment: @Ôrel Are yes, totally missed that.

Comment: My problem the content of array in the for loop becomes blank.

Comment: i try foreach and the result is same

Comment: Please copy past the output of var_dump before the loop, during the loop and after the loop. Are you sure you are not doing something with result into the loop you didn't show us ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop here to achieve the desired result. Try this:

```
foreach ( $result as $array ) {
    echo implode(",", $array->keyword);
}
```

Note: most people will use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), [`join`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) is simply an alias for implode. It's fine to use either in your code.

Comment: I normally use `$arr`, just typed it out in full as the user seems quite new and wasn't sure if they would understand `$arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, may be fix your problem

```
<?php
  $str = '[{"keyword": ["123","456","789"] , "name" :"hello" },
    {"keyword": ["abc","def","ghi"] , "name" :"bye" },
    {"keyword": ["987","654","321"] , "name" :"hello" }]';
  $obj = json_decode($str);
  foreach($obj as $elem){
      echo implode(",",$elem->keyword)."\n";
  }
?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/790394